# Transversality of stable and unstable manifolds along a homoclinic orbit

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, transversality

Consider the system
$$ \begin{cases} \dot{x}=f(x,\alpha), \\ \dot{\alpha}=0,  \end{cases} 
$$ with $(x,\alpha)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The system has a homoclinic orbit at $\alpha=0$ and we  assume there is a curve of saddles which has the stable and unstable invariant manifolds $\mathcal{W}^s$ and $\mathcal{W}^u$.

In [Kuznetsov's book, p. 231](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edturaev/kuznetsov.pdf), it is written that $\mathcal{W}^s$ and $\mathcal{W}^u$ intersect transversally along the homoclinic orbit if and only if the Melnikov integral is non-zero. In the book one of the directions is proved, namely, if the intersection is non-transerval, then the integral is zero. However, it says nothing about the remaining direction, i.e., if the intersection is transversal, then the integral is zero. And I do not see that this is trivial...
Does anyone have an idea how to prove that?